# How to build webGL globe animation as seen in Piano.io website

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, glsl, webgl

I've been exploring around webGL and threejs recently and noticed the piano.io website globe animation is really good.

There are many examples to create the dotted globe but I am wondering how to implement the 2 parts - (1) shows up the card and dot on the various points, (2) earthquake? or pulse like effect animations.

I would really appreciate if there is a minimum glsl code example or strategy to implement these two. (I would write with react and typescript or js)

[image]

Here is the actual animation link: https://piano.io/

Answer (score 0):

In your example if you check the network, the point cloud are a 3D model `point-cloud.bin`.

But a approach with code is possible, as I have done on this website, https://benbdetroit.com/.
The steps:

- You get a map texture;
- You pick points on that texture and project it on sphere.
  [image]

For the "earthquake" effect:

- There is a circle growing;
- This circle collides with points and they grow with a random offset on there axis from center and random scale.